# Method to determine if path string is local or remote machine for Java

Tags: java

I want to determine if a file path string is on the local machine or a remote server/ network location.

Is there any Java API to determine the above behaviour ?

Comment: On *NIX systems you can't really tell... If the file is accessible on the file system, it can be on the local harddrive, on a usb-stick, or on some file system in china...

Comment: @aioobe: It's actually the same way in Windows. Even down to the point where you can mount a network share *on a directory of an existing drive*.

Comment: But you have the system-integrated `//someserver/someSharedFolder` right?

Comment: @aioobe: that's right, but that's not the *only* way to access a remote share, so you *still* need some way to find out if a given path is local or remote.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`Files.getFileStore()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#getFileStore%28java.nio.file.Path%29) to get the [`FileStore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html) representing the partition/mount/drive that the file is stored on.

Then calling [`FileStore.type()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/FileStore.html#type%28%29) can give you *some* information on what kind of device that `FileStore` is. However, that information is implementation dependent, so unfortunately there is no standardized way to evaluate it.

Having just checked this on my Ubuntu sytem it gives rather unhelpful values for the task at hand:

- `/` reports as `rootfs`
- `/tmp` is `tmpfs`
- `/proc` is `proc`
- `/sys` is `sysfs`.
- a mounted windows share reports as `cifs`

In other words: it seems to report *directly* what `mount` claims to be the fstype. Mapping that to "network", "physical", "synthetic" requires a lot of "knowledge" built into your code and is pretty fragile.

Comment: Note: Available on Java 1.7 and upwards.

Comment: That's where it is if it is anywhere, but I'm not about to install Java 7 just to check.